# InstantWP Alpine Linux - repository tag for world dependency 'apk-tools@edge' does not exist

Tags: repository, alpine-linux, mariadb, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am using InstantWP which installs a virtual server running Alpine Linux. InstantWP is for running a local version of Wordpress. It has MariaDB 10.1 installed, which isn't the latest version of mariadb.

So I try `sudo apk add mariadb`. This returns an error:

```
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
WARNING: The repository tag for world dependency 'apk-tools@edge' does not exist
ERROR: Not committing changes due to missing repository tags. Use --force to override.
```

I tried doing `sudo apk update` and inspecting `apk/repositories` is showing:

```
#/media/cdrom/apks
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main
#http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community
#http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
#http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

Nothing seems to fix this. What is going on?

The main issue is when I import my sql file from MySQL 8.0 via phpmyadmin, it returns an error: `#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'` and I read running the latest version of `mariadb` might be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning suggests, it seems apk expects that the `@edge` repository tag is present, but it indeed missing from your `/etc/apk/repositories` file.

For adding the `edge` tag and repository, add the following line to your repositories file:

```
@edge http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```

This enables the edge repository, and tags it with the `@edge` tag.
After doing this, run `apk update` and try repeating MariaDB installation.

For more details on Alpine repository tagging and pinning, refer to:
[Alpine Wiki - Packages and Repositories - Repository pinning](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management).